# CocoaPods podspec generated from GitHub not matching any source_files

Tags: github, include, cocoapods, lint, podspec

I am developing a Swift 2 project which includes many CocoaPods that work and am struggling to create a podspec file for this [OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary) class from GitHub since the author didn't create a Podfile.  I ran:

```
pod spec create "OrderedDictionary|https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary"
```

which created `OrderedDictionary.podspec` in the root of my project directory:

```
#
#  Be sure to run `pod spec lint OrderedDictionary.podspec' to ensure this is a
#  valid spec and to remove all comments including this before submitting the spec.
#
#  To learn more about Podspec attributes see http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html
#  To see working Podspecs in the CocoaPods repo see https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  # ―――  Spec Metadata  ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  These will help people to find your library, and whilst it
  #  can feel like a chore to fill in it's definitely to your advantage. The
  #  summary should be tweet-length, and the description more in depth.
  #

  s.name         = "OrderedDictionary"
  s.version      = "0.5"
  s.summary      = "An implementation of OrderedDictionary in Swift"

  # This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
  #   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
  #   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
  #   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
  #   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!
  s.description  = "This is a lightweight implementation of an ordered dictionary data structure in Swift packed into a µframework."

  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary"
  # s.screenshots  = "www.example.com/screenshots_1.gif", "www.example.com/screenshots_2.gif"


  # ―――  Spec License  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Licensing your code is important. See http://choosealicense.com for more info.
  #  CocoaPods will detect a license file if there is a named LICENSE*
  #  Popular ones are 'MIT', 'BSD' and 'Apache License, Version 2.0'.
  #

  s.license      = "MIT"
  # s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.md" }


  # ――― Author Metadata  ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Specify the authors of the library, with email addresses. Email addresses
  #  of the authors are extracted from the SCM log. E.g. $ git log. CocoaPods also
  #  accepts just a name if you'd rather not provide an email address.
  #
  #  Specify a social_media_url where others can refer to, for example a twitter
  #  profile URL.
  #

  s.author             = { "Lukas Kubanek" => "lukas.kubanek@me.com" }
  # Or just: s.author    = "Lukas Kubanek"
  # s.authors            = { "Lukas Kubanek" => "lukas.kubanek@me.com" }
  # s.social_media_url   = "http://twitter.com/Lukas Kubanek"

  # ――― Platform Specifics ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  If this Pod runs only on iOS or OS X, then specify the platform and
  #  the deployment target. You can optionally include the target after the platform.
  #

  # s.platform     = :ios
  s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"

  #  When using multiple platforms
  s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
  # s.osx.deployment_target = "10.7"
  # s.watchos.deployment_target = "2.0"
  # s.tvos.deployment_target = "9.0"


  # ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Specify the location from where the source should be retrieved.
  #  Supports git, hg, bzr, svn and HTTP.
  #

  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary.git", :tag => "v0.5" }


  # ――― Source Code ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  CocoaPods is smart about how it includes source code. For source files
  #  giving a folder will include any swift, h, m, mm, c & cpp files.
  #  For header files it will include any header in the folder.
  #  Not including the public_header_files will make all headers public.
  #

  s.source_files  = "Sources"
#s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

  # s.public_header_files = "Classes/**/*.h"


  # ――― Resources ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  A list of resources included with the Pod. These are copied into the
  #  target bundle with a build phase script. Anything else will be cleaned.
  #  You can preserve files from being cleaned, please don't preserve
  #  non-essential files like tests, examples and documentation.
  #

  # s.resource  = "icon.png"
  # s.resources = "Resources/*.png"

  # s.preserve_paths = "FilesToSave", "MoreFilesToSave"


  # ――― Project Linking ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  Link your library with frameworks, or libraries. Libraries do not include
  #  the lib prefix of their name.
  #

  # s.framework  = "SomeFramework"
  # s.frameworks = "SomeFramework", "AnotherFramework"

  # s.library   = "iconv"
  # s.libraries = "iconv", "xml2"


  # ――― Project Settings ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
  #
  #  If your library depends on compiler flags you can set them in the xcconfig hash
  #  where they will only apply to your library. If you depend on other Podspecs
  #  you can include multiple dependencies to ensure it works.

  # s.requires_arc = true

  # s.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2" }
  # s.dependency "JSONKit", "~> 1.4"

end
```

next to my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'OrderedDictionary', :podspec => "OrderedDictionary.podspec"
```

I ran:

`pod cache clean OrderedDictionary && pod install`

which created a `Pods/OrderedDictionary` group under the `Pods` project.

**Unfortunately the group is empty, so the project fails to build at:**

```
import OrderedDictionary
```

`error: No such module 'OrderedDictionary'`

Linting passes:

`pod spec lint OrderedDictionary.podspec --verbose`

**For the life of me I can't get `OrderedDictionary.swift` and `OrderedDictionary.h` to copy into the pod's group in the project.**

The weird thing is that I did see `OrderedDictionary.h` appear in the group once but couldn't get it to happen again.  I'm concerned that CocoaPods might not be idempotent, but could be overlooking something obvious.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Xcode 7.2.1 (7C1002), OS X 10.10.5 (14F27), CocoaPods 0.39.0

Comment: Your podspec works well on my system via both cocoapods v0.39.0 and v1.0.0.beta.3 . Please post your Podfile as also.

Comment: Updated with Podfile and environment version info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question based on [IvanRublev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214789/cocoapods-podspec-generated-from-github-not-matching-any-source-files?noredirect=1#comment58155895_35214789).  I tried my podspec in this [IceCreamShop CocoaPods swift example](http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/IceCreamShop_Final_Swift2.0.zip) and then **after it worked there, it worked in my original project.**

Reproduction steps:

After I wrote this question last night, I bit the bullet and downloaded the zip of the OrderedDictionary GitHub project, expanded it to the root level of my project directory, moved my podspec inside it, and changed my Podfile to say:

```
pod 'OrderedDictionary', :path => "OrderedDictionary"
```

**That allowed me to use it as a development pod, and I saw OrderedDictionary.swift and OrderedDictionary.h copied into the pod's group.**

Today after I got IceCreamShop to work, I removed the OrderedDictionary directory from my project directory, moved my podspec back to the root level of my project directory, and changed the Podfile back to:

```
pod 'OrderedDictionary', :podspec => "OrderedDictionary.podspec"
```

**The pod now worked, even though I didn't change anything.**

I believe this may be a caching issue in CocoaPods, causing it to be inconsistent for one of the following reasons:

- Being nontransparent, where issues like the subproject failing to build or a process being terminated leave the cache in an inconsistent state that allow us to detect the presence of the cache by its malfunction.
- Not being invalidated correctly, so once it found files in my project dir, it somehow remembered them and was able to include them after they were removed.
- Loads and stores behaving differently depending on where they are performed, allowing side effects to affect future loads and stores.
- Having temporal issues where loads and stores are nondeterministic because timeouts take priority over the source of truth.
- A cosmic ray from a distant galaxy flipping a bit in the cache causing my wave state to collapse into the reality where I spent hours chasing a bug instead of the one where I never knew the bug existed.

I like CocoaPods and realize this is all a bit tongue in cheek, but caching issues often have a detrimental impact on productivity and I would recommend that all projects have an option to disable their cache as well as have it run an internal consistency check every time it's used.

Here are some commands that might help someone experiencing similar problems:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/

sudo rm -rf Pods/
pod install
```